# How to use decodeURIComponent in JS in Facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to use decodeURIComponent in a JS function inside Facebook instead of using urldecode in PHP. But I keep getting the following error :

```
Error: a194182563946198_decodeURIComponent is not defined
```

Can anyone kindly help ?

Thanks.

-
Ahsan

Answer (score 0):

On a second thought, I am using a PHP intermediate file that does the work on ajax call. :)

-
ahsan